# Use Core Data With UITableView With Sections That Have A Different Number Of Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

So I have a TableView contains sections that can possibly hold a different amount of cells depending on the user input for rows for detail. I trying to learn more about saving and want make a simple app that allows the user to save recipe ingredients. For example I can have 5 different sections containing 5 different types of food like -> banana: amount-2 Calories-10 Details-Slice, Apple amount-3 Calories-20 Details-Mash <-. The User would then click done and his or her recipe name will be saved and displayed on a cell in another table view. Once the user clicks on it he/she can see what he/she put and can edit it if he/she desires. I was told that Core Data would be best for this type of saving.

How could I save all the info in a organized way. I know how to save individual cells using Core Data but what is hard about this is each section can contain a unique number of cells and then this data is all saved into one data entry. It's like an array inside of an array inside of an array. I also have a feeling that I have to use dictionaries. I can't seem to structure all of this data. Can anyone help or have any tips on how I should attack this? I'm using Swift by the way.

Picture of what one section of the TableView might look like:

[image: Picture of what one section of the TableView might look like.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways you can tackle this situation. The first solution that came to mind was storing a unique array for each section that you want to display. E.g. a fruit array, vegetable array, etc. If you did this, when you fetch from Core Data you would store the items in the appropriate arrays and do something similar to the following within your `numberOfRowsForSection`:

```
switch (section) {
case 0:
    return fruit.count()
case 1:
    return vegetable.count()
default:
    return 0
}
```

That switch statement will be called according to whichever section you are in at the time. If you went with a different route like a dictionary, instead of returning the count of the different array, you could `return typeDict.objectForKey("fruit")` instead.

Comment: Okay so lets say for starters the items in my recipe are ["chicken", "onion", "orange peeling", "garlic"]. They each are given a section respective to their array element. Are you saying I then should break it down even further and put them in respective arrays for fruit, meat, etc. Or would they each get their own individual array. Ex. chickenArray, onionArray, orangePeelingArray. Also, noticing that the sections have certain values of their own like amount, calories, and detail rows. Should I then save those values as an array of dictionaries. Ex. chickenArray = [amount: 1, detail: [hi,bye]]

Comment: Also then I name that recipe chicken recipe. So now chicken recipe holds 4 arrays that holds unique dictionaries. Then I make a sandwich recipe that now holds 5 arrays with their dictionaries. What would you do to organize all these things so they it doesn't all get out of hand. I do not know much about Core Data and have been watching videos all day trying to figure things out but wouldn't this force me to create a lot of entities?

Comment: I was just using fruit and vegetable as an example since I didn't know what items you would have. =) From what you just described, it sounds like you could do this with just 2 entities... Recipe and Ingredient. Recipe could contain attributes: recipeId, name, prep time, etc. Ingredient could contain: name, amount, detail, recipeId. This way, you add each recipe and connect them using the recipe Id (or relationships). You said you don't know much about Core Data, but do you have any general database experience?

Comment: Honestly I don't have much database experience but I can figure things out easily with examples and I'm more of a visual person. I'm understanding your response though. Just to make this clear by your example the ingredients will be more like an array of dictionaries that hold all the values and then they will be apart of one recipe linked by the recipeId(considering you meant each ingredient and connect them instead of "each recipe and connect them". This will then allow me to display each recipe in a new uitableview as cell and when the user clicks of them it will displayed the ingredents.

Comment: In their own sections. This is all making sense and seems not to difficult. However, I must admit that I don't necessarily know the syntax to make this happen. It's kind of confusing to know things are being saved but you can't see the actual array. Sorry if I sound like too much of an amatuer but I'm just being honest.

Comment: Yes it sounds like you've got it. =D Core Data is kind of confusing at first, and it helps to add in NSLog statements to see the items you are working with to help visualize a little bit.